# Compare algorithm complexity between Big O, Theta and Omega

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

Good evening people,

I would like some help to compare a big-O and a Θ algorithm.
I can understand how to compare two big-O's but something troubles
my understanding on how to compare big-O with Θ or big-O with Ω etc etc.

I will post some examples below :

Θ(2ⁿ)     vs      Ο(2ⁿ)
  Θ(n<sup>0.6</sup>)  vs      Θ(n<sup>logn</sup>)
  O(n)      vs      Ω(n⋅logn)

Comment: What's your current understanding of what `Θ`, `O`, and `Ω` are?

Comment: O the upper limit , Ω the lower limit and Θ ισ the precise estimation of magnitude

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Θ(2^n)   vs   Ο(2^n)

I have one thing that's the same size as an elephant[*], and another thing that's no bigger than an elephant. Compare their sizes.

> Θ(n^0.6)  vs Θ(n^logn)

`n^log n` is bigger than `n^0.6`, because `log n` is bigger than a constant. But I can't be bothered thinking of animals for them.

> O(n)  vs  Ω(nlogn)

I have one thing that's no bigger than a mouse, and another thing that's no smaller than a cat. Compare their sizes.

[*] erm... as the thing and the elephant tend to infinity they're the same size, anyway. The analogy isn't perfect, but the point is that big-O means "is no bigger than", big-Omega means "is no smaller than", and big-Theta means, "is both no bigger than and no smaller than". "Bigger" and "smaller" are both judged by the same standard, actually meaning "`f(n)` no bigger/smaller in magnitude than a constant multiple times `g(n)`, for sufficiently large `n`"

Comment: thank you very much! i laughed so hard about the elephant comment! ok so to put it in comparison! my understanding was an O(n) and now its an Ω(2^n) :P